# I explore the final frontier

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I explore the final frontier
> Or do harm to ships that cruise it
> Hackers may know much about me
> I've played with a deadly gambit
>
> Turn your back on me? I'll stab you
> I do what the law won't allow
> In my trades I'll try to cheat you
> One of me is very big now
>
> A river, a valley
> Cars, books, films, brews
> I made quakes get bigger ...
> Are you now confused?

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> Rogue

I explore the final frontier

> A rogue planet explores space

Or do harm to ships that cruise it

> A rogue wave endangers ships

Hackers may know much about me

> Rogue security software is used by hackers

I've played with a deadly gambit

> References Rogue and Gambit's relationship from X-Men

Turn your back on me? I'll stab you

> Rogues are notorious for backstabbing, especially in online video games

I do what the law won't allow

> Rogues are frequently criminals

In my trades I'll try to cheat you

> A rogue trader describes dishonest tradesmen

One of me is very big now

> Rogue One is a very popular movie that released this week.

A river, a valley

> Rogue River and Rogue Valley in Oregon

Cars, books, films, brews

> Nissan Rogue, many books and films with Rogue in the title, Rogue Brewery

I made quakes get bigger ...

> Rogue Entertainment produced expansions for the Quake video games

Comment: +1 very nice!  You're missing just a couple of the clues: the first 3 are not correct, and neither is the trades one.

Comment: Rogue trader might be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_trader)

Comment: I take it you found the disambiguation page :)  Well done.  (The hackers clue was intended to reference the game Hack, a descendant of an earlier game that fits the riddle; your answer works just as well.)  Welcome to PSE - hope you stay awhile!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I've read a number of puzzles on here, but this is the first (and probably the last) I have solved.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to say

> Ice.

**Explanations -**

I explore the final frontier

> The Antarctic Ice Sheet is the last place on Earth yet to be fully explored by man - the "final frontier". Alternately, as Scimonster pointed out, frozen Alaska is known as "The Last Frontier". For a non-terrestrial example, comets are large balls of ice that whizz through space - the *true* final frontier.

Or do harm to ships that cruise it

> Icebergs.

Hackers may know much about me

> Google tells me there's something called "Intrusion Countermeasure Electronics" (ICE) - security programs that protect against hackers.

I've played with a deadly gambit

> No idea, sadly.

Turn your back on me? I'll stab you
I do what the law won't allow

> To "ice" someone is to murder them, such as by stabbing. With an icepick, perhaps? Alternately, if we "turn our back" on the melting ice caps, it'll come back to bite us through rising sea levels.

In my trades I'll try to cheat you

> Again, Google tells me there was a roaring "ice trade" back in the 19th century, don't know whether that's relevant though.

One of me is very big now

> The Antarctic Ice Sheet is 14,000,000 sq.km, which is pretty darn big.

A river, a valley

> Rivers often spring from melting glaciers; you can also get glacial valleys

Cars

> Cars are powered by Internal Combustion Engines (ICE)

Books

> I'm thinking "A Song Of **Ice** And Fire"

Films

> The actor (and formerly rapper) known as "Ice Cube"

Brews

> Ice tea (tea is often referred to as a "brew")

I made quakes get bigger ...

> To quote that one Pokemon comic, "That thing where water gets into cracks in the ground, then freezes and expands, and the cracks get bigger?"

Comment: Final frontier could also be Alaska.

Comment: Good call, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: For a wrong answer this fits surprisingly many of the clues. But the correct answer will fit all of them with no feeling of hand waving.  +1 for a great attempt.

Comment: Darn... thanks anyway, though! This is gonna bug me now...

Answer (score 4):

**(Updated) Is it -**

> **Bang**

**Explanations -**

I explore the final frontier
Or do harm to ships that cruise it

> Big Bang Theory may represent the final frontier. And a bang can destroy the ships/spaceships travelling to outer space.

Hackers may know much about me

> It's a term for exclamation point stating - *"Common alternate name for EXCL"*

I've played with a deadly gambit

> Card game [Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang!_(card_game)) has 12 bandit characters.

Turn your back on me? I'll stab you
I do what the law won't allow

> Bang can be used as stabbing in the back.

In my trades I'll try to cheat you

> Not sure..

One of me is very big now

> Big Bang Theory?

A river, a valley
Cars, books, films, brews

> [Bang River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%BA%B1ng_River), [Chitty Chitty Bang Bang(car)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitty_Chitty_Bang_Bang_(car)), [The Bang-Bang Club Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bang-Bang_Club_(book)), [Bang Bang Film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang_Bang!)

I made quakes get bigger ...

> Again, either Big Bang or [Sonic Boom/Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_boom)

---

**Old answer -**

> **Nuke**

**Explanations -**

I explore the final frontier
Or do harm to ships that cruise it

> Final frontier may refer to High-altitude nuclear explosion. And the nuclear missiles destroying the ships/cruise.

Hackers may know much about me

> Nuke is a Hacker's term stating - *"To intentionally delete the entire contents of a given directory or storage volume."*

I've played with a deadly gambit

> Still thinking about this one..

Turn your back on me? I'll stab you
I do what the law won't allow

> Nuclear weapons usage is strictly prohibited.

In my trades I'll try to cheat you

> Nuclear weapons trade may be..

One of me is very big now

> Tsar Bomba may be.

A river, a valley
Cars, books, films, brews
I made quakes get bigger ...

> Nuclear explosions may tend to seismic activities leading to quakes.

Comment: Nope, sorry. The correct answer fits all the clues well, if you know how.

Comment: Sorry, still no. :)